# How to stop logging from HTTP Server

Tags: python, logging, httpserver

I want to stop logging for my python server since I always get this text when the localhost website is called:

```
[28/Oct/2021 22:58:15] code 501, message Unsupported method ('GET')
[28/Oct/2021 22:58:15] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 501 -
```

I already tried it with the logging module as you can see in my code example:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
import logging
import threading
import logging


def server_run():
    httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 4443), BaseHTTPRequestHandler)
    httpd.serve_forever()
    logging.getLogger("HTTPServer").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.getLogger("BaseHTTPRequestHandler").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
    logging.getLogger("http").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)

threading.Thread(target=server_run).start()
print("Server running")
```

Comment: is `.serve_forever` a blocking function? could it be possible that it blocks until the server is shut down and only then does the `logging` module do any configuration? would it fix the problem if you moved the `logging` stuff before calling `.serve_forever`?

Comment: It still gets printed when moving it before .serve_forever

Comment: you may actully want to maybe use `logging.basicConfig` and set some simple handler that writes the log to file or sth like that: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subclass the handler class you use and override the log_message method to use logging the way you need.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.log_message